# Using the Replace VBA function in MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am trying to work out how to apply the Replace function in MS Project.  I have looked the material at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.replace  but I still can't get it to work.

The code below related to a problem where I am using MS Project to schedule training sessions (these are the 'tasks') and adding Users (resources) to these sessions (tasks).  Some of these Users have to travel so I have created a custom field to be able to track the number of people and their location that have to travel to a session.

```
'T.Text16 is the column for the Travel flag itself
'T.Text5 is the location of the session
'R.Text 3 is the home location of the User
Sub User_Travel_Flag()
'Identitifies the number of user locations in a session that had to travel 
to the training location
'(i.e. the home users location is not part of the total)
Dim Count As String

 If MsgBox("Have you allocated User to sessions first?", vbYesNo + 
 vbInformation, "Check User allocation") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks
    T.Text16 = ""
Next T

For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks

Application.StatusBar = "Checking task ID " & T.ID & "...."

For Each asn In T.Assignments
    If Left(asn.ResourceName, 1) = "U" Then  'Find the User Resources

        If T.Text5 <> asn.Resource.Text3 Then 'the Training Facility is 
         different to the User's home facility
         ' print resource's initials and standard rate
            If T.Text16 = "" Then
                T.Text16 = asn.Resource.Text3 & "x1"
            ElseIf InStr(1, T.Text16, asn.Resource.Text3) = 0 Then
                T.Text16 = T.Text16 & ", " & asn.Resource.Text3 & "x1"
            Else
                Count = Mid(T.Text16, InStr(1, T.Text16, asn.Resource.Text3) + Len(asn.Resource.Text3) + 1, 1)
                'THIS REPLACE PART DOESNT WORK.  It says the field is an issue
                **Replace Field:=T.Text16, Test:="equals", Value:=asn.Resource.Text3 & " " & Count, Replacement:=asn.Resource.Text3 & " " & Count + 1, ReplaceAll:=False**

            End If
        End If
    End If
Next asn
Next T

Application.StatusBar = True

MsgBox "The flagging of the location of users that have to travel to 
training 
has been successfully completed.", vbInformation, "Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message you are getting? thank you

Comment: Its all good now I have worked it out.  I didn't realise you could just use the standard Replace function like in MS Excel.                                           
                                                                                                                
                    T.Text16 = Replace(T.Text16, asn.Resource.Text3 & "x" & Count, 
                asn.Resource.Text3 & "x" & Count + 1)

Comment: I was wondering why you didn't the std Replace() function